# Is there a way to send multiple JS requests to an API at once?

Tags: javascript, api, email, verify

I'm trying to verify multiple email-adresses as once using briteverify.

Their example request is:

```
https://bpi.briteverify.com/emails.json?address=johndoe@briteverify.com&apikey=XXX
```

It works great for a single adress, now I want to verify more than one mail in one request. 
Is there a way to do this?

Im not a programmer by any means, so if its super easy - sorry. :/

Comment: Why don't you use their web interface?
I'm sorry to tell you that from what i've read it's not possible.

Answer (score 0):

Put the addresses in the array and execute this little script

```js
(function(){
var url = "https://bpi.briteverify.com/emails.json?apikey=XXX";
var emails = [
  'johndoe@briteverify.com',
  'johnsmith@briteverify.com',
  'user@briteverify.com'
];
  
var success = function(data){
    console.log(data.address + " is " + (data.valid?"valid":"invalid"));
};
  
var checkEmail = function(email){
  $.ajax({
    url: url,
    data: {
      address: email
    },
    success: success
  });
};

for(var email in emails){
  checkEmail(email); 
}
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```